# How to understand $E(X\mid B)$ in the measure theory way

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

From undergraduate probability course, we learn $P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$ given $P(B)>0$. And we learn that if $(X,Y)$ has a joint density $f(x,y)$, we can calculate marginal density $f_X(x)=\int_\mathbb{R} f(x,y)\,dy$ and define the conditional expectation $E(Y\mid X=x)=\int_\mathbb{R} \frac{yf(x,y)}{f_X(x)}\,dy$. Note here both two definitions give us a real number result.

But above definition may have problem if $P(B)=0,f_X(x)=0$ or if $(X,Y)$ doesn't have a joint density. Hence in graduate courses, we define the conditional expectation of $Y$ given r.v $X$ by the unique r.v $E(Y\mid X)\in \sigma(X)$ and $\int_A Y \, dP=\int_A E(Y\mid X)\,dP$ for all $A\in \sigma(X)$. And we further define $P(A\mid X)=E(1_A\mid X)$. Note the given condition is a $\sigma-$ algebra, hence the conditional expectation is a r.v.

Then in this framework, how to define $P(A\mid B)$ or $E(X\mid B)$ where $B$ is a measurable set? In particular, how to define $E(Y\mid X=x)$. I think for consistence, the result should also be a constant (or a constant r.v.).

Comment: Well of course the "above definition" has a problem when $P(B) = 0$...$P(A|B)$ means, literally, what is the probability of $A$ happening if $B$ happens.  If it's not possible for $B$ to happen then this question makes no sense--what are the chances of me winning the lottery given that the roll of two standard dice is 21??

Comment: @Jared So you mean, even in a graduate course, when we want to verify $E(Y|X=x)$ has a given version, we still use the definition in elementary probability, and implicitly assume $f_X(x)\not =0$?

Comment: No, one does not assume that $f_X(x)\ne0$. Rather one uses the fact that $E(Y\mid X)$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable hence there exists some measurable $u$ such that $E(Y\mid X)=u(X)$ almost surely. This allows to define $E(Y\mid X=x)=u(x)$, for every $x$. Warning: this does not define each specific value $u(x)$ uniquely, only $P_X$-almost surely uniquely. // There is no definition of $E(Y\mid B)$ for every event $B$.

Comment: @Did So we already know such $u$ exist, and to identify such $u$, if joint density exists, we use the way in elementary probability? Is my understanding correct? And if not for any event $B$, how about some $B$ related with $Y$, such as $E(Y|Y\le t)$ or $E(Y|\max\{X,Y\}\le t)$for given $t$?

Comment: @JohnZHANG: If $P(B)>0$ then $E(Y\mid B)=E(Y\mathbf{1}_B)/P(B)$.

Comment: @StefanHansen Thanks for your reply. Then if $X$ is a continuous r.v., then for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $P(X=x)=0$, so can we define $E(X|X=x)$? Intuitively, I thought it should be $x$.

Comment: That's defined by Did in a previous comment. And you're right, it should be $x$.

Comment: @StefanHansen Well, actually, not necessarily for every $x$.

Comment: @Did: Sorry, for $P_X$-almost-all $x$.